# How can I call a method of an activity in another activity which not using static references?

Tags: android, android-activity

Maybe this question is duplicate but the answers used static references to archive this. I know that static variables can cause memory leak so we should avoid using them.

How can I do that without using static method or references?

Comment: `How can I call a method of an activity in another activity which not using static references?` : not good practice. if method is useful for both classes then move it in a separate normal java class and use it in both class. or use `LocalBroadcastManager ` to communicate between Activities

Comment: use static **method** :-)

Comment: As my question I don't want to use static methods.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? Why do you want to call method of another activity at all? I am sure there is a better way than calling the method.

Comment: Are you using Application Class (Extends Application) and put method on that class?

Comment: I need call some special methods in activity

Comment: `static` methods can be placed anywhere. They do not inherently cause memory leaks, no matter where they are or how they are used. `static` variables are a different story.

Comment: Please explain what your "special methods" are doing. You can't call a method in an `Activity` from another `Activity` if that method needs to reference any of the `Activity`-specific stuff (member variables of the `Activity`, the activity's `Context`, etc.). If the method doesn't use any `Activity`-specific stuff, you can move the method out of the `Activity` or make it `static` or both.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity 
{  

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

}      

// Utility.method() used somewhere in FirstActivity
}

public class Utility {

public static void method()
{

}  

}

public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
{  

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    Utility.method();

}
}
```